# Is it possible to ignore the "ps check" when starting solr?

Tags: solr

I have a system that runs Solr under Kubernetes as part of a CI/CD pipeline.  That same system also normally runs Solr on the "bare metal."  In upgrading to Solr-7.7.1 I discovered that the bare metal Solr would not start if the k8s Solr is already running, because it incorrectly concludes that Solr is already running.

This was probably a problem in Solr 6.x, too, but the bare metal processes (which are running under systemd) are winning the race condition with the k8s processes.  It'd probably be OK in production, too, but I would like to not have to worry about this in the future when starting and stopping Solr.

The issue is in the Solr script (solr-7.7.1/bin/solr):

```
if [[ "$SCRIPT_CMD" == "start" ]]; then
  # see if Solr is already running
  SOLR_PID=`solr_pid_by_port "$SOLR_PORT"`

  if [ -z "$SOLR_PID" ]; then
    # not found using the pid file ... but use ps to ensure not found
    SOLR_PID=`ps auxww | grep start\.jar | grep -w "\-Djetty\.port=$SOLR_PORT" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | sort -r`
  fi

  if [ "$SOLR_PID" != "" ]; then
    echo -e "\nPort $SOLR_PORT is already being used by another process (pid: $SOLR_PID)\nPlease choose a different port using the -p option.\n"
    exit 1
  fi
```

If the bare metal Solr isn't running, then SOLR_PID will not be found and the second check for a process whose jetty.port matches my desired (i.e., default Solr port) shouldn't find a match.

However, that ps command captures processes running under kubelet's dockerd, leading to a false positive here.

Is there some way--perhaps using a setting in solr.in.sh--to change the result of the `if [ -z $SOLR_PID ];` test so that the script doesn't look at ps output?

Comment: Any reason why you have to use `bin/start` when you're running the containers? Those will have well-defined behaviors and known paths - and shutting down is synonymous with shutting down the container itself?

Comment: Well, the containers start up with the built in CMD of the Solr image. Not doing anything special there.  I know I could customize the start script for the bare metal instance, but I’d rather not do that, for long term compatibility reasons with the official distribution.